# useEffect is in infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a component which once once it rendered I need to redirect a user to another path and I'm using useEffect hook of react but it's getting rendered over and over and over without stopping:

```
const App: FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (condition) {
      setMessage("you are being redirected");
      setTimeout(() => {
        location.href = `http://localhost:4000/myurl`;
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      setMessage("you are logged in");
      setTimeout(() => {
        <Redirect to={"/pages"} />;
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <>
      {message}
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path="/login/stb" render={() => <Code />} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: and where is you /pages route defined?

Comment: I'm using a monorepo project and its defined in another repo of the project

Comment: Is `setMessage` setting a `message` state variable in the component?

Comment: I was rendering the message based on this condition, I will add now the updates which what I tried

Comment: I have added the updates which I did before

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `setMessage` is setting a `message` state variable in the component. This occurs during every run of `useEffect`. State changes will cause your component to rerender.

Basically, the flow causing the loop is this:

1. Initial component render
2. useEffect is run
3. `message` state is updated
4. Component rerenders due to state change
5. useEffect is run as it's trigged on `message` change
6. Back to step 3

If you want `useEffect` to only run on initial render, and redirect after a user has logged in, you could change it to something like this:

```js
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (someConditionHere) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    loggedIn ? <Redirect to={"/pages"} /> :
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/login/stb" render={() => <Code />} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

I don't know everything about the setup, so that's simplifying and making some assumptions.

Comment: but it should redirect to the given url which cause a render of a new component, no ?

Comment: if so, then what do you think the fix is ?

Answer (score 0):

Charlie Dobson described the answer perfectly. I would recommend to set the `someConditionHere` he recommends as the first state you expect `message` to have or of course the opposite, the last state with a not operator. I did so in my own similar issue, which was `event === undefined`

Comment: Should probably just be a comment under the answer then.

Comment: @Martin I would comment, but I cannot as this would require 50 reputation, which is a dumb rule imo.